# De que manera puedo identificar que hay numeros que se repiten dentro de un sudoku(filas y columnas), c++

Tags: c++, matrices

```
#include <iostream>
#define F 9
#define C 9

using namespace std;

void mostrar(int sudoku[F][C]);
void evaluar(int sudoku[F][C]);

int main()
{
    //Declarando las matriz
    int sudoku[F][C];

    //Almacenando los datos
    int i,j; 
    for (i = 0; i < F; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < C; j++)
        {
            printf("Digite un numero del 0 al 9 (%d, %d): ", i,j);
            scanf("%d", &sudoku[i][j]);
        }  
    }    
     //llamando a la funciones
    mostrar(sudoku);
    evaluar(sudoku);            
}

void mostrar(int sudoku[F][C])
{
    //Mostrando la matriz
    int i,j;
    for (i = 0; i < F; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < C; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", sudoku[i][j]);
        }    
        printf("\n");          
    }
    cout<<"\n";
} 
//funcion evaluar
void evaluar(int sudoku [F][C])
{   
    int fila,columna;
    int t = 0;
    int f[0];
    int contador = 0;
    for (fila = 0; fila != F; fila++)
    {
        for (columna = 0; columna != C; columna++)
        {
            if (fila == 2 ){
                t = sudoku[fila][columna];                        
            }           
        }
    } 
    cout<<t;
}
```

Hasta el momento eso es lo que llevo de codigo, ya cree la matriz que el mismo usario llena, el problema es que no se de que manera podria comparar las filas y las columnas de manera que si encontra que hay numeros repetidos en alguna fila o alguna columna me diga en que posicion estan.

No se si sea necesario guardar las filas i en una nueva variable, o como deberia hacerlo.

Answer (score 0):

La manera más sencilla de encontrar repeticiones es usando un set (`std::set<int>`), así pues para buscarlas en columnas sería de esta manera:

```
std::set<int> valores;

// Miramos la columna (por ejemplo) 4
for (int fila = 0; fila != F; ++fila)
{
    auto [i, b] = valores.insert(sudoku[4][fila]);
    // Si falla la inserción, es un valor repetido.
    if (!b)
        std::cout << sudoku[4][fila] " está repetido\n";
}
```

Yo te aconsejaría una completa restructuración de tu código para acomodar unas funciones de verificación:

1. No uses macros para definir constantes, usa expresiones constantes:

   ```
   constexpr unsigned F = 9u;
   constexpr unsigned C = 9u;
   ```
2. Pasa el tablero por referencia, puedes crear un alias para facilitar la tarea:

   ```
   using Tablero = unsigned[C][F];

   void mostrar(const Tablero &sudoku);
   void evaluar(const Tablero &sudoku);
   ```

   Columnas y filas están intercambiadas porque una formación de *m*×*n* se distribuye en memoria como *m* formaciones de *n* elementos.
3. Crea funciones para verificar filas, columnas y cuadrículas, deben devolver falso si la verificación siguiendo las reglas del sudoku fallan:

   ```
   bool verifica_fila(unsigned fila, const Tablero &sudoku);
   bool verifica_columna(unsigned columna, const Tablero &sudoku);
   bool verifica_cuadricula(unsigned cuadricula, const Tablero &sudoku);
   ```

   Se pasa el tablero de Sudoku por referencia constante porque dentro de las funciones no hay intención de modificar sus valores.
4. En C++, se muestran datos por consola usando el objeto `std::cout`, la función `printf` pertenece a C.
5. En C++, se leen datos desde consola usando el objeto `std::cin`, la función `scanf` pertenece a C.

Con esos consejos, tu código podría parecerse a:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

constexpr unsigned F = 9u;
constexpr unsigned C = 9u;

using Tablero = unsigned[C][F];

bool verifica_fila(unsigned fila, const Tablero &sudoku)
{
    std::set<int> valores;
    for (const auto &valor : sudoku[fila])
    {
        auto [i, b] = valores.insert(valor);
        if (!b)
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}

bool verifica_columna(unsigned columna, const Tablero &sudoku)
{
    std::set<int> valores;
    for (unsigned fila = 0u; fila != F; ++fila)
    {
        auto [i, b] = valores.insert(sudoku[fila][columna]);
        if (!b)
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}

bool verifica_cuadricula(unsigned cuadricula, const Tablero &sudoku)
{
    return true;
}

bool evaluar(const Tablero &sudoku)
{   
    for (unsigned i = 0u; i != 9u; ++i)
        if (!(verifica_fila(i, sudoku) && verifica_columna(i, sudoku) && verifica_cuadricula(i, sudoku)))
            return false;
    return true;
}       

int main()
{
    Tablero Sudoku;

    unsigned y = 1u;
    for (auto &fila : Sudoku)
    {
        unsigned x = 0u;
        for (auto &valor : fila)
        {
            std::cout << "Digite un numero del 1 al 9 (" << ++x << ", " << y << "): ";
            std::cin >> valor;
        }
        ++y;
    }

    for (const auto &fila : Sudoku)
    {
        for (const auto &valor : fila)
            std::cout << valor;
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    std::cout << "Es un Sudoku " << (evaluar(Sudoku) ? "correcto" : "incorrecto");

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pVRtb9owEP4c/4ork2ii0KmE8hpgH7rxB7ZvDE3GGGQtOMiJK9DEXy@72A4hLUzThgQ9P3f3@J67c9lu97Bh7HT6ICRL9IrDWKRZrjjdTkmFZTyfEsJSmeV8v1OgZSY2kq9gBhMY6via69m5iM6E3MA3uky4ShEsI@bPi/lsgQHLNE3ghSuxFoz@WIuE@meW4tQCQ3@maGZ6lf7UAflFvCxfjUZY3ljIfAovNEkVz2LirVMFvk2jOscc44IR2Nx5wbsIiIcUngmYixYsF1ie4/goZMZV7ptjgIyeWIN/t8Qcz1M810rCmiYZR9eRkBLKlUbk@FYUSxO9lRe6HPDP0moNwqofdWzNuwnMYgjD4vA3@i77MXdVLf5fr6YrJZi@HGWF/Un1VV6ORWuq/FtpAPC2L8I1RRQdwT3EloigVOXXtw1b46ig2Xw/tFvuSmMVEVzrV10T2A8hOFfYUiF9I7xU9dUQ4bPwzloOqKWty9HbfTbDHrloN@hzwt6KR@gio3wBbjNMhl0yluocxmNofBYbkXN8oSD1tihmxRNoA01gCH6jCAnDvYlsgTkezCEYQSOu2ISEqVvYAj3iNwwPbm/ePcxrQm6@3rL2et3nq2ro/Xd57y6tq/ySFQrthVaGXy6YqwI@QYOlSnGWpw28toH/CctjEFfb/4jjPJ26pEOeSI/0yYAMSZtExo7QGhLrGxh7YOwIMRvbRayPdtug1tczeAfxgqmP3w5akeEo8oYm3kZEiD2Z3z7@bRtfx93YNXjPcAzJK1sndJOdHrARExaGEf0N)</kbd>.